# SSRS Subscription Date Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have an SSRS report published, and I would like the subscription to sub in today's date as the date parameter every day when it gets emailed out.

But I would like no default date to be set when the user accesses the report directly, so that they may manipulate to whichever date they choose.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to create another parameter like @isForSubscription (and you put it as hidden), that accept True or False (you have to put default_value = False) and you change the default date value parameter to something like

```
= iif(Parameters!isForSubscription.Value is True, Today(), nothing)
```

Then, when you configure your subscription, you just need to put `@isForSubscription=True`

I don't remember exactly but I did something similar once and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! I just ended up just including an if statement in my stored proc that changed my run parameter to todays date if it was NULL, then set the subscription to pass null for the parameter!